# How can I add tooltip on content of table

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-ui, jtable, tooltip

I am very new to java script. I wanted to add tooltip to given below content. There is one way of doing it that is we can do by Adding title to every td tag. Now How can I add title to every td with same value. I am not allowed to touch html code below written here as It is automatic generated code using Jtbale Plugin.

```
<tbody>
<tr class="jtable-data-row jtable-row-even">
    <td>admin-ui</td>
    <td>/admin/manage/client</td>
    <td>Client Manager</td>
    <td>Used for redirecting to Client Management page</td>

</tr>
<tr class="jtable-data-row">
    <td>admin-ui</td>
    <td>/admin/manage/configuration</td>
    <td>Configuration Manager</td>
    <td>Used for redirecting to configuration page</td>

</tr>
```

Any Help Will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `title`-tag via the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)-function and just invoke the tooltip after that:

```
$('table td').attr('title', 'testtitle').tooltip();
```

To expand the tooltip to the width of it's content you may have to add the following css:

```
.ui-tooltip{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jwuf4gs5/1/)**

Comment: content is coming out of tooltip box.  any solution /

Comment: @praveenjain What is the  `tooltip box` ? please edit your question to include all the relevant information

Comment: My mean with tooltip box is that When we hover mouse on some text. Then that Text is being highlighted. Highlighted text comes in a box. So am talking about that box.

Comment: You Please try with given script. I think you will come to know about that.


$('table td').attr('title', 'testtitleasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadqasdad').tooltip();

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, its for all td's because I'm not sure what do you mean by 'every td with same value':

```
$(function(){
    $.each($('td'), function() {
        $(this).attr("title", $(this).text());
    });    
});
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3tg2qn60/1/).

Answer (score 1):

To add `title` to the `td` with same value you can do it as below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/Lc9sxmdx/)**

```
$.each($('td'),function(){
   if($(this).text()==="admin-ui")
       $(this).attr('title',$(this).text())
});
```